# Return XML and JSON and PDF from Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

having a request like this

`{
    "report": "score",
    "name": "CHRIS WAKE",
    "format": "xml"
}`

I want to to return an XML format of the response based on the `"format": "xml"` parameter which can also be json or pdf.

What i have now returns the XML as a string which does not show the XML tags in the preview tab of postman. This also does not work in the browse-able API version.

Many thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

`django-rest-framework` supported XML directly before but now it has been included as a third party package.
Have a look [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#xml) for more information.